# Different kind of checked exceptions - Guarantee to only throw X

Tags: language-design, exceptions

It is a widely held position that checked exceptions as implemented in Java are a bad idea.  If you mark a method as throwing, calling code has to either catch the exception, or be marked as throwing, too.  For this reason, it is said that exception specifications are contagious.  Consequently, they are being removed from C++ (with exception of `noexcept`).

I wonder if you could implement a different kind of checked exceptions.  Instead of **"Caller must catch this"**, they would mean **"I will only ever throw this"**.

The calling scope will not have to be changed at all.  It is helps me as a writer of the called function to understand what I will possibly throw - if I decide to add an annotation.  It would also allow the possible exceptions to be shown during code completion.  I could imagine special fatal exceptions will always be allowed, like `OutOfMemoryException`, or Python's `KeyboardInterrupt`.

For example (pseudocode):

```
// simple case (could actually be inferred)
string lookupString(string key) throws only KeyError {
    return m_map[key];
}

// complex failing example
string readFromFile(string filename) throws IndexError {
    File f = File.Open(filename);
    return f.readline();
}
// -> Compilation error:
// File.Open may cause IOError, but readFromFile guarantees to only throw IndexError
// (optional:)
// readFromFile suggests it will throw IndexError,
// but no operation in it may possibly throw IndexError.
```

In case you give no specification, I would suggest to allow any exception (`throw Throwable`). I imagine adding this feature to an existing language, and this would be the only backwards-compatible option. For a new language, you think about a different default.

To deal with legacy code (in an external library), there could be a way to tell the compiler that a certain function or block of code only can ever throw certain exceptions. Conceptually a bit like `unsafe` in C#:

```
I swear throws only ParseError {
    return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

I am not aware of any language that implements this weaker kind of checked exceptions.  It seems to me they would have a lot of benefits, but without the drawbacks of Java's checked exceptions.  Are there any reasons that this idea wouldn't work?  Has any language successfully implemented this, or tried and failed?

(Note, please do not read this as a question looking for a language recommendation and then close it.  This is a question about language design, I would like to understand the benefits and drawbacks of this approach better.  Possible answers I could imagine would be: "Yes, this has been attempted in language XY, but doesn't work very well because of interplay with generics." or "No, this has never been implemented, but it is a great idea.  Because of *<language-theoretic argument>*, this can be implemented in a sound type system.  See this work of Foobar for more information.")

Comment: I'm still missing part of the proposal. What would be the semantics of a procedure in your hypothetical language that doesn't carry *any* specifications?

Comment: I agree with @KilianFoth: as soon as a method without `throws` is used the callee must either be `nothrow`/`noexcept` or the caller must be declared `throws Throwable`. I imagine this results in a great percentage of the codebase being declared as `throws Throwable` with junior/mid-level programmers; and that is effectively equal to unchecked exceptions.

Comment: @KilianFoth Good point, I made an edit. Since I imagine this could be added to an existing language, the backwards-compatible default would be `throws Throwable` (aka allow anything). But this is up to debate.

I imagine using it gradually... if you write a new piece of code, or have a method which crashed on you with an unexpected exception, you can use the compiler to help you "tame" a certain piece of code. I often have trouble telling whether a function call can throw an exception from deep down the call stack.

Comment: For your first paragraph : https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/445k0a/java_checked_exception_is_bad/ . TL;DR : checked exception is provided by Java, if some can't properly use them, that's not Java's fault. `The general consensus is that RuntimeExceptions indicate some condition that should never have happened and usually means a bug in the program`, which fall in the most cases of exception you're supposed to encouter.

Comment: It's a nice attempt to fill the void of documenting exceptions at the code level.  However it breaks down pretty quick.  Say a function that calls two other functions each declared as throwing only a different exception.  How do you declare that third function exception declaration ?  Option one is to declare the common parent to both but this quickly leads to Throwable being the only viable option.  You could wrap each call and throw a new exception, cleaner but requires more code but that leads us right back to arguments against checked exceptions.

Comment: @Newtopian you can already declare multiple types of checked exceptions per method in Java (for example), so I don't see *that* as a problem.

Comment: @JacobRaihle indeed we can ! I (mis)understood from the OP's description that the "only throw" declaration would only support a single exception argument.  Indeed a list or exceptions would render my first argument irrelevant.  Furthermore the auto-throw feature could be made smarter than just Throwable and automatically adds the list of sub-calls.  Second argument remains but with this kind of help from the compiler it is made much weaker.  That is programmers who are not bothered with dealing with exceptions now can keep on going, The others will have an alternative at least.

Comment: The questions you have to ask yourself of any exception implementation (or, for that matter, any computing technique) are: 1.  What problem does it solve, and 2.  Are the benefits worth the costs?  Programming language features have additional considerations: 3.  Is it intuitive, and 4. Does it have broad applicability?

Comment: (1) As others have pointed out, Java clearly allows [declaring a list of exceptions that are thrown by a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html).  (2) Further, Java allows the declaring of throwing java.lang.Throwable.  So, what is different in your proposal?

Comment: @ErikEidt: In Java, if I call a method that has exception specifications, I *as a caller **must*** either catch that exception, or declare that I may throw it, too. I am not proposing any check at the caller side. Rather, in my proposal, you can *guarentee that only certain exceptions leave a method* (or maybe block). The check is performed on the callee side only. If I specify some allowed exception types on a scope, and the compiler can't prove that I can only leak those, it is a compile time error.

Comment: This seems like it would be more useful as an IDE feature than a language feature. An IDE can walk the call tree to see what exceptions are thrown, which are handled, and produce a far more accurate list of possible exceptions than a list maintained by a human. It would be considerably less hassle as well.

Comment: Are you familiar with Modular Anchored Exception Declarations? Have you seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2228897/2988)? Are you familiar with Common Lisp Conditions? With Smalltalk Exceptions?

Comment: @Morgen Yes, but a typical method will raise many possible exceptions from deep down the call stack (NullPointerException, IndexError, ...). Its not enough to just enumerate them all. If I want to make a failure recoverable, I introduce a new exception, e.g. ParsingError, and announce my method throws only that. Calling code should only have to deal with that high-level failure, not internals of my code. Now the compiler complains that I could generate a KeyError in line 123 in my method - I wasn't aware of that! - and I can handle it properly.

Comment: @JörgWMittag No thanks, I'll have a look! (It seems like my proposal is not mentioned in that thread though.)

Comment: @jdm It sounds like that's more of a design philosophy difference. I'm of the opinion that if code I call can produce an exception which I don't handle, then that exception is no longer an implementation detail. For me, a list of what could be thrown, along with the information on what might throw it, would be endlessly useful. Recoverable exceptions and non-recoverable errors should have different type hierarchies, so explicitly flagging unrecoverable ones doesn't look to me like a big win over simply having a list of what can be thrown by a particular statement.

Comment: The caller must catch all exceptions. If not, they break encapsulation and are processed out of context. Code smell: a stack trace is added to exceptions so the developer can figure out what's going wrong. Exceptions have been called a comefrom statement and like unrestricted goto's, unrestricted exceptions easily create spaghetti code.

Comment: @shawnhcorey: Well, there are many different attitudes towards exceptions. But I share the worry about unrestricted exceptions "leaking" out. That is exactly the motivation behind this question: You'd add a keyword to a scope, and the compiler makes sure you can only throw approved exceptions, if any, from out of the scope.

Comment: Just throwing my 2c in: I used to be a *Java* developer. No more, but the one thing I miss most is checked exceptions. The way they forced me to handle bad paths. Alternative approaches that come to mind that come close are: the variant type (à la *ML*, or did it originate in *Algol*?), and (checked) multiple value return as in *Go*.

Comment: I feel this will come down to an opinion. Can this be done? I'm sure it can be. Are the effects what you want?
For example, if I do this in an IOC type of architecture and swap out a dependency, all of a sudden the caller on the dependency now could end up different exceptions. So maybe we'll allow declaring this on interfaces. Solved. But now you've forced your dependency to only throw a specific set of exceptions. A junior / medior developer will simply wrap the entire method in a catch and rethrow a generic exception. Is that an improvement on not knowing the possible exceptions?

Comment: `It is a widely held position that checked exceptions as implemented in Java are a bad idea.` -- *Widely held by whom?*  While it is true that Java is the only language (that I know of) that has chosen this design tradeoff, there *are* benefits to using checked exceptions.  Languages like C# have chosen to avoid them, not because that is a "widely held" position, but because they decided the benefits weren't worth the costs.

Comment: @jdm in your code example `string lookupString(string key) throws only KeyError { return m_map[key]; }` do you want the compiler to refuse to compile because your function must have NullPointerException in its "throws only" list since m_map could be null and `return m_map[key];` could throw because of that?  How would you tell the function that m_map will never be null?

Comment: FWIW, this is how error propagation is handled in Rust, and it’s handled similarly in some other ML-family languages, too. (Technically Rust doesn’t implement it as exceptions, but in terms of type specification it’s very similar.)

Answer (score 1):

Has been done in [Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ValaForJavaProgrammers#Exceptions).

The caveat is that not handling the exceptions in code is a compile-time warning, the idea being that one of the main issues with java checked exceptions is that when prototyping, people tend to catch and ignore the exceptions rather than considering proper error handling. If the error does occur at runtime and has not been handled in code, the default handling logic in Vala is to immediately exit.

Comment: I think this is not the same though. The compiler warns about ignored exceptions (errors). But there is not a way to say "dear compiler please make sure that *this* function cannot leak a NullPointerException". (I don't know if NPEs are even a thing in Vala, but that's just an example.)

Comment: The default in Vala is that no exceptions are thrown by a function. If a function has no `throws ...` clause, then it will never throw an exception. If any error does occur, whether it's a null dereference, an unhandled exception, or something else the program will be terminated.

Comment: Right, but what I suggested is a *super-strict* function where the *compiler* checks that null dereferences, unhandled exceptions etc. can never occur. (If you want to do more than simple calculations or call other *super-strict* functions, you could probably mark your code as safe manually.) Termination in case of a bug is exactly what I want to avoid. I'd like to catch these corner cases at compile time.